# Stubbing API with webdriver and cucumber

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, cucumber

I want to run some BDD tests against my application using Webdriver configured with Cucumber, but would like to stub out my API. Preferably I'd like to not use Express, as I want my CI server to execute these tests and Express would add complexity.

I haven't been able to find any guidance online about injecting `nock` or `fetch-mock` into the browser context from wdio. I would like to setup my stubbed calls before each scenario, and then clean things up after the scenario.

Here are the relevant bits of my `wdio.conf.js`. Obviously it won't work as written, but I hope illustrates what I would like to do. If anyone has useful advice the deviates from this direction, I'd still love to hear it.

```
/**
 * Gets executed before test execution begins. At this point you can access to all global
 * variables like `browser`. It is the perfect place to define custom commands.
 * @param {Array.<Object>} capabilities list of capabilities details
 * @param {Array.<String>} specs List of spec file paths that are to be run
 */
before: function (capabilities, specs) {
    fetchMock = require('fetch-mock');

    browser.execute(() => { 
       injectFetchMockSomehow(fetchMock);
    }, fetchMock); 
},

/**
 * Runs before a Cucumber scenario
 * @param {Object} scenario scenario details
 */
beforeScenario: function (scenario) {
    fetchMock.get('/foo', {hello: 'world'});
},

/**
 * Runs after a Cucumber scenario
 * @param {Object} scenario scenario details
 */
afterScenario: function (scenario) {
    fetchMock.reset()
    fetchMock.restore();
},
```

Comment: This would depend on how the APIs are called in the browser client side code. Does it use jQuery to make the API calls or does it use something else?

Comment: My client-code simply uses fetch. What I would like to do is set up the stub in `beforeScenario` and tear the stub down in `afterScenario`.

Comment: What I am trying to understand is that the API call is being made by your web app or your server or you test code? Who is making this api call?

Comment: The API call is made by my web app. The API is an external dependency, so I want it stubbed during the course of BDD test execution.

Comment: Do you have access to modify the app? Or you want to inject using JavaScript? The reason being if you don't modify the app then you will need to injecting mocking code after every page change. Because changes made to JS at run-time once a page reloads or a new page is refereshed